# How to upload a file through FTP in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I used below code to upload a file through FTP. From Line: 9 to 14, ít is showing error that "The attribute 'connection' is not valid for the  tag. (Found: [connection, localfile, passive, action, failifexists, remotefile])" Please let me know where I went wrong. Thanks in advance

```
1.<cftry>    
2.  <cfftp connection="Myftp"  
3.  action="open"  
4.  server="#ftpurl#"
5.  username="#form.ftpusername#"
6.  password="#form.ftppassword#">
7.  stoponerror="Yes">

8.  Did it open connection? <cfoutput>#cfftp.succeeded#</cfoutput><br />                            
9.  <cfftp connection = "Myftp"
10. action = "PutFile"
11. localFile="D:\home\\wwwroot\localfile.txt"
12. remoteFile="remotefile.txt"
13. failifexists="no"
14. passive = "Yes">

15. Did it put the file? <cfoutput>#cfftp.succeeded#</cfoutput><br />                       
16. <cfftp action="close" connection="Myftp">
17. <cfcatch>
18.     <cfset errText = "Please enter valid FTP details" />
19.     <cfset err = err + 1 />
20. </cfcatch>          
21.</cftry>
```

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with the code you posted. Which version of ColdFusion are you running?

Comment: I'm using Coldfusion version 8

Comment: are you using CF8, or CF8.0.1? Have you tried taking it out? it's only required if action = "open" or "closed"

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In eclipse editor, it is showing errors, using underlines with red color. Irrespective of errors, I executed the code. it uploaded file successfully

Comment: Aha, it sounds like it was just a CFEclipse bug. I can replicate it in my cfeclipse install

Comment: Always trust actual behaviour over the claims of an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments on the question, the "error" here is a bug in CFEclipse dictionary files, resulting in incorrect labelling of "connection" as an invalid attribute.

The code provided is valid and executes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a closing tag on line 6 which looks out of place.

```
6.  password="#form.ftppassword#">
7.  stoponerror="Yes">
```

should instead be

```
6.  password="#form.ftppassword#"
7.  stoponerror="Yes">
```

Comment: In this case, you need to at least paste the code **WITH** the corrections and then highlight this fact.

Comment: Done. I hope that is better.

Answer (score -1):

to use `<cffile>` tag is best prectice to upload a file on server instead of `<cftfp>` tag.
it is easy and compact. see syntax..

```
<cffile 
action = "upload"
destination = "full pathname"
fileField = "form field"
accept = "MIME type|file type"
attributes = "file attribute or list"
mode = "permission"
nameConflict = "behavior"
result = "result name">
```

example :

```
 <cfset destination = expandPath("www\img\QuesImages") />
 <cffile action="Upload" 
         fileField="QuesPhoto"   <!--name of input tag in form-->
         destination="#destination#" 
         nameConflict="Overwrite" 
         accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png">
```

Comment: While this is true for general use, the OP may have had his own reasons for using ftp.

Comment: Using cffile is NOT best practise - it is DIFFERENT practise. cffile handles a file uploaded via a HTTP POST request. cfftp sends/receives files using FTP protocol.

Answer (score -2):

```
Correct parameters are 

 9.  <cfftp connection = "Myftp"
10. action = "PutFile"
11. localFile="D:\home\\wwwroot\localfile.txt"
12. remoteFile="remotefile.txt"
13. stoponerror="Yes"
14. passive = "Yes">`
```

Comment: What makes this correct? You've added attribute `stoponerror` (which already defaults to yes) and removed `failifexists` (which is a valid attribute) with no explanation of why.

Answer (score -2):

You can use bellow  code to upload a file.........code is contents of a single file

```
<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfoutput>#CFCATCH.message#</cfoutput>
    Unable to open FTP. Please check Server / Username / Password and then try again.1
    <cfabort>
</cfcatch>
```

```
<cfcatch type="Any">
    <cfoutput>C:#CFCATCH.message#</cfoutput>
    Unable to change directory. Please check server directory and then try again.2
    <cfabort>
</cfcatch>
```

Exists...replacing...

File already exist, Unable to remove. Please check User Access. 
 Error: D:#CFCATCH.message#3

```
    <cfcatch type="Any">
        <cfoutput>D:#CFCATCH.message#<br />
                    #CFCATCH.Detail#
        </cfoutput><br />
        There was a problem uploading your file. Please check User Access and then try again.4
        <cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again. Error: #CFCATCH.message#5